# Cannot install anything in Ubuntu14.04. Error:The package gitkraken needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: git, ubuntu-14.04, apt, gitkraken

Recently, I try to use my ubuntu 14.04 to unzip 7Z files. So I need to install p7zip-full. But when I tried to install it , I get a error like this:
```

```
emma@emma-AMAX:~$ sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package gitkraken needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

```
And my ubuntu software center cannot open too.
I donnot know how to uninstall Gitkraken.
I used Gitkraken to git push some files to mu github repo.
But I don't what happend exactly.

other command output same error:
```

```
emma@emma-AMAX:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit http://storage.googleapis.com stable InRelease
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntukylin.com:10006 xenial InRelease [18.1 kB]          
Ign http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty InRelease                                 
Get:2 http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-security InRelease [65.9 kB]            
Hit http://storage.googleapis.com stable/jdk1.8 amd64 Packages                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntukylin.com:10006 xenial/main amd64 Packages            
Hit http://archive.ubuntukylin.com:10006 xenial/main i386 Packages             
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Get:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease [15.5 kB]                      
Get:4 http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-updates InRelease [65.9 kB]             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Get:5 http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-proposed InRelease [65.9 kB]            
Get:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages [3,383 B]            
Hit http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-backports InRelease                       
Get:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages [3,383 B]             
Hit http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty Release.gpg                               
Get:8 http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-security/main Sources [130 kB] 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Get:9 http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-security/restricted Sources [4,941 B]   
Get:10 http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-security/universe Sources [52.5 kB]    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Get:11 http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources [3,206 B]  
Get:12 http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages [611 kB]
Hit https://packagecloud.io trusty/main Sources          
Ign http://storage.googleapis.com stable/jdk1.8 Translation-en_US              
Ign http://storage.googleapis.com stable/jdk1.8 Translation-en
Get:13 http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages [14.0 kB]
Get:14 http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages [157 kB]
Get:15 http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [4,133 B]
Get:16 http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages [569 kB]   
Get:17 http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages [13.8 kB]
Get:18 http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages [157 kB]
Get:19 http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages [4,289 B]
Get:20 http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-updates/main Sources [398 kB]          
Get:21 http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources [6,327 B]   
Get:22 http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-updates/universe Sources [178 kB]      
Get:23 http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources [7,767 B]   
Get:24 http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages [978 kB]   
Get:25 http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [17.1 kB]
Get:26 http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages [405 kB]
Get:27 http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [14.3 kB]
Get:28 http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages [937 kB]    
Get:29 http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages [16.9 kB]
Get:30 http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages [406 kB]
Get:31 http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [14.6 kB]
Get:32 http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-proposed/main Sources [111 kB]         
Get:33 http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-proposed/restricted Sources [782 B]    
Get:34 http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-proposed/universe Sources [16.4 kB]    
Get:35 http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-proposed/multiverse Sources [832 B]    
Get:36 http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-proposed/main amd64 Packages [86.9 kB] 
Get:37 http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-proposed/restricted amd64 Packages [769 B]
Get:38 http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-proposed/universe amd64 Packages [10.3 kB]
Get:39 http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-proposed/multiverse amd64 Packages [28 B]
Get:40 http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-proposed/main i386 Packages [84.3 kB]  
Get:41 http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-proposed/restricted i386 Packages [772 B]
Get:42 http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-proposed/universe i386 Packages [10.3 kB]
Get:43 http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-proposed/multiverse i386 Packages [729 B]
Hit http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-backports/main Sources                    
Hit http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources              
Hit http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-backports/universe Sources                
Hit http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources              
Hit http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages             
Hit http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages       
Hit http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages         
Hit http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages       
Hit http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages              
Hit http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages        
Hit http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages          
Hit http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages        
Hit http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty Release                                   
Hit http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty/main Sources                              
Hit http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty/restricted Sources                        
Hit http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty/universe Sources                          
Hit http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty/multiverse Sources                        
Hit http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                       
Hit http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages                 
Hit http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages                   
Hit http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages                 
Hit http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty/main i386 Packages                        
Hit http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages                  
Hit http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                    
Hit http://mirrors.aliyun.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages                  
Fetched 5,694 kB in 37s (151 kB/s)                                             
W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386sudo/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386sudo/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-proposed/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386sudo/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386sudo/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386sudo/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntukylin.com:10006/ubuntukylin/dists/xenial/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386sudo/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386sudo/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jtaylor/ipython/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386sudo/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386sudo/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
emma@emma-AMAX:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package gitkraken needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
emma@emma-AMAX:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package gitkraken needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solve this question by

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-all gitkraken
```

Then I can install other package normally.

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download Gitkaren zip then you can use this link.

http://www.wikihow.com/Uninstall-Ubuntu-Software

OR if you want to remove existing package from system then you can follow this link : http://www.wikihow.com/Uninstall-Ubuntu-Software

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have solve this question.